# Efficient way to extract elements from JSON using Python 2.7

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have a JSON with the following structure and the structure is stored in a variable called json_object_variable:

```
parentkey: [
  { 
    childkey1 : value,
    childkey2 : value,
    childkey3 : [
      {
         grandchildKey1 : value,
         grandchildKey2 : value,
         ...
      },
      {
         grandchildKey1 : value,
         grandchildKey2 : value,
         ...
      },
      {
         grandchildKey1 : value,
         grandchildKey2 : value,
         ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  { 
    childkey1 : value,
    childkey2 : value,
    childkey3 : [
      {
         grandchildKey1 : value,
         grandchildKey2 : value,
         ...
      },
      {
         grandchildKey1 : value,
         grandchildKey2 : value,
         ...
      },
      {
         grandchildKey1 : value,
         grandchildKey2 : value,
         ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
 ]
```

I would like to extract all the grandchildKey2 values from corresponding to each list object in this JSON structure using Python is the most efficient way.

Please find below a pseudocode of my execution:

```
for element in json_object_variable['parentkey']:
    for grandchild_element in element['childkey3']:
        print grandchild_element['grandchildKey2']
```

My JSON contains around 300000 elements, hence I wanted to find out if there an efficient way to pull the grandchildKey2 values.

Comment: If you need all `grandchildKey2`, then there's no other way than looping(other solution may exists, but it will be same)

Comment: My concern is that 300,000 is just the size of parentKey list, individual childKeys contain 100,000+ elements, and by doing a loop on loop the program is probably going to run forever.

Comment: You surely need to improve/breakup your data structure. Also system might run out of memory

Comment: I have no control over the data structure as it is coming out of a get request. The only thing I can control is the amount of parentKey elements I retrieve at once.